# Question about XmlReader.Read() method

Tags: .net, xml

I am confused about the XmlReader.Read() output. Hope someone could explain it.

It seems the XmlReader.Read() method always gives **an extra blank line**?

Below is my code:

```
    public static void TestXML()
    {
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(@"d:\snapshot_skeleton.xml");

        //r.MoveToContent();
        while (r.Read())
        {
            Console.Write(new String('.', r.Depth));
            Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
        }
    }
```

Below is the output:

```
xml
    <-----------------what is this?
person
.   <-----------------what is this?
.name
..  <-----------------what is this?
.name
.
.gender
..
.gender
.
.age
..
.age
.
person
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty lines are caused by text nodes, which don't have a `Name`.

See the table [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.name.aspx). Immediately before it is explained:

> All other node types return an empty
>   string.